# Why am I getting the RabbitMQ exchange exception?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

Here are my queues setting for tests, they are incorrect but they work:

```
mq:
  username: guest
  password: guest
  host: localhost
  port: ${QA_RABBIT_LISTENER}
  ig-smev3:
    listener:
      vhost: /
      exchangeName: igSmev3Listener
      queueName: igSmev3-ListenerQueue
      routingKey: igSmev3-Listener
    producer:
      vhost: /
      exchangeName: igSmev3Producer
      queueName: igSmev3-ProducerQueue
      routingKey: igSmev3-Producer
```

If I set

```
vhost: /
      exchangeName: igSmev3Producer
      queueName: igSmev3ProducerQueue
      routingKey: igSmev3Producer
```

I will get an error:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'igSmev3Listener' in vhost '/': received 'fanout' but current is 'direct', class-id=40, method-id=10)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'igSmev3Listener' in vhost '/': received 'fanout' but current is 'direct'

You have already an `igSmev3Listener` exchange on the broker and its type is `fanout`, but you provide the same name and with default type - `direct`.

Consider to remove that exchange before starting your application.

This feels like a Deja Vu with this similar question with similar properties: [How to set x-dead-letter-exchange in Rabbit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792713/how-to-set-x-dead-letter-exchange-in-rabbit)

Comment: I don't have the exchange, it's starting only with a Docker Rabbit container

Comment: I'm testing it using Concordian

Comment: OK. Then you create it somewhere else  in your application with a `fanout` type...

Comment: Yes... I had to pay attention but I didn't. The problem is solved. Thank you!